# Is it possible to .SkipWhile(n => (function)) in linq where (function) looks at the next x rows?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Lets say I have an entity framework object called Measurement. One measurement has many DataPoints and each datapoint has an attribute Length. Say I want to skip the first x datapoints, until the next 2 datapoints are strictly increasing.
For example, if the datapoints have the lengths {1, 1.2, 1.1 0.2, 1, 2, 3, 4}, I have the list {0.2, 1, 2, 3, 4}.

I thought something like (from elmt in Measurement.Datapoints select datapoints.length).SkipWhile(n =>) but I don't know how the lambdafunction can 'look ahead'?

Comment: Each `measurement` must hold the reference to the *next*. Have you tried using a LinkedList?

Comment: I don't think this is something you can express (easily) in LINQ. Maybe, in this case, a simple `foreach` with your logic could be the better choice.

Comment: Hm, I'm using entity framework so the Measurement and Datapoint classes are autogenerated.

Comment: I don't think so, the direct way is to use it like array, iterate over it by it's index, you will need to check if it is the last item or not as the last item has no next to it.... for loop will finish it

Comment: It would probably be easier to use a `for` loop, but `SkipWhile` has an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile.aspx) that uses the current object and its index.

Comment: Ok, I guess I've been thinking along the wrong lines for this.

Comment: You would have to create a projection that includes the "next x rows" along with the current record.

Comment: After finding one successful increasing pair, is there a chance for the DataPoints to again break the increasing order?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to pull the entire query into a list then it's simple enough:

```
var list = data.ToList();

var query = list.SkipWhile((item, index) => index + 2 < list.Count &&
    item < list[index + 1] && list[index + 1] < list[index + 2]);
```

If it's important that you maintain deferred execution then the problem is a bit harder, you could do it with this function:

```
public IEnumerable<TSource> NextTwoStrictlyIncreasing<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TSource, bool> isStrictlyIncreasing)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;
        var twoBack = iterator.Current;

        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;
        var oneBack = iterator.Current;

        bool previousIsIncreasing = false;
        bool isIncreasing = false;


        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            isIncreasing = isStrictlyIncreasing(oneBack, iterator.Current);
            if (isIncreasing && previousIsIncreasing)
            {
                yield return twoBack;
                yield return oneBack;
                yield return iterator.Current;
                while (iterator.MoveNext())
                    yield return iterator.Current;
                yield break;
            }
            twoBack = oneBack;
            oneBack = iterator.Current;
            previousIsIncreasing = isIncreasing;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't express that the next two items are strictly increasing; it expresses that the next two items form an arithmetic progression `(a, a + 1, a + 2)`.

Comment: @Jason I assumed that was what the OP meant given that they didn't include `0.2` in their sample output.  That said, it's simple enough to change the `+1 ==` to `<` if that's desirable.

Comment: Ha, good point. If "strictly increasing" is literally what the OP meant, 0.2 *should* be included. Nice implementation of the deferred version. Of course, it's all for naught if the OP needs it to execute in SQL on the server side. :-/

Comment: @Jason If they need a version for the query provider then I'm reasonably confident that it's not possible.  Based on my knowledge of SQL, it doesn't provide the operations to do this.  You'd need to make a stored proc that uses a cursor to do this if you wanted all of the work done on the db end, and that couldn't be done with LINQ to a db provider.

Comment: Not completely true. He can change his data model in a way that it can be done in simple SQL. So the answer to his question is if it's need to be done server side in SQL then change data model else use your deferred implementation.

Comment: @Jason Then by all means provide such a solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var seq = new double[]  {1, 1.2, 1.1, 0.2, 1, 2, 3, 4};

            var state = -1.0;
            var last = 0.0;
            var r = seq.Where(x =>
                                   {
                                       var res = last > x ? state : ++state;
                                       last = x;
                                       return res > 1;
                                   }
                ).ToArray();
```

or

```
var r = seq.SkipWhile(x =>
                                   {
                                       var res = last > x ? state : ++state;
                                       last = x;
                                       return res < 2;
                                   }
                ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of messy, but it does what you want:

```
IEnumerable<DataPoint> FilterInitialDecreasing(IEnumerable<DataPoint> items)
{
    var buffer = new Queue<DataPoint>();
    int increasingCount = 0;
    int prior = int.MinValue;

    foreach (int data in items.DataPoints)
    {
        switch(increasingCount)
        {

           case 2:
        {
            yield return data;
        }
        else if (data.Length > prior)
        {
           increasingCount++;
           prior = data.Length;
           buffer.EnQueue(data);

           if (increasingCount >2)
           {
               yield return Queue.Dequeue();
               yield return Queue.Dequeue();
               yield return data;
           }
        }
        else
        {
           increasingCount = 0;
           buffer = new Queue<DataPoint>();
           prior = int.MinValue;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete and universal solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = new double[] { 1, 1.2, 1.1, 0.2, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        var output = input.SkipWhileNext(T => T.IsIncreasing(), 2);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{{ {0} }}", string.Join("; ", output)));
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsIncreasing<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        T last = default(T);
        bool flag = false;

        foreach (T item in e)
        {
            if (flag)
            {
                if (item.CompareTo(last) <= 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                flag = true;
            }

            last = item;
        }

        return true;
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> SkipWhileNext<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e, Func<IEnumerable<T>, bool> predicate, int count)
    {
        count++;
        Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>(count);

        foreach (T item in e)
        {
            queue.Enqueue(item);

            if (queue.Count == count)
            {
                if (predicate(queue))
                {
                    yield return queue.Dequeue();
                }
                else
                {
                    queue.Dequeue();
                }
            }
        }

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            yield return queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

### Outputs as expected: { 0,2; 1; 2; 3; 4 }.